# capistrano deployment with use_sudo=true - permissions problem

Tags: capistrano

i am trying to do a deployment with capistrano to newly installed Ubuntu server

i am deploying to directory /var/www, owned by root, so i need to set use_sudo to true

while i execute commands with run "#{try_sudo} command" without problem, svn checkout doesn't work with sudo prefix

i try

```
set :deploy_via, :export
```

and it throws

```
Can't make directory '/var/www/pr_name/releases/20091217171253': Permission denied
```

during checkout

i imagine adding "try_sudo" prefix to "svn export" would help, but where can i edit the one it uses in deploy_via?

--

if on other hand i don't use use_sudo, and set /var/www/ directory ownership to myuser, i still cannot deploy - some of my deployment commands set folders ownership to apache user www-data and then i get something like:

```
changing ownership of `/var/www/pr_name/current/specificdirectory': Operation not permitted
```

which, if i understand correctly, has to be done with sudo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the sudo helper solved the problem.
Here is an example:

```
run "#{sudo} chown root:root /etc/my.cnf"
```

Comment: Don't leave us hanging! What is "sudo helper"? I can't find references to it in the Capistrano docs.

Comment: explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431925/capistrano-is-hanging-when-prompting-for-sudo-password-to-an-ubuntu-box
(note the comment about deprecation and new format)

Answer (score 0):

Try `cap deploy:setup`