# capistrano(3) deployment with use_sudo=true - undefined local variable or method default_run_options for main:Object

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, sudo, capistrano3

I want to `cap production deploy:check`, but I got the error message `mkdir: cannot create directory /var/www: Permission denied`.
I'm using Capistrano3 and Rails4.

I think the sudo couldn't work in my case.

deploy.rb

```
set :application, 'appname.com'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:user/myapp.git'
set :user, 'username'
set :use_sudo, true
set :branch, 'master'


set :deploy_to, '/var/www/myapp'
set :pty, true
set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

 desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
   on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
  end
 end

 after :restart, :clear_cache do
   on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
  end
 end

 after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'

end
```

production.rb

```
set :stage, :production
set :branch, 'master'
role :all, %w{appname.com}
server 'appname.com', user: 'username', port: 'port_number', roles: %w{web app db}, my_property: :my_value
```

I read these articles.

[Capistrano is hanging when prompting for SUDO password to an Ubuntu box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431925/capistrano-is-hanging-when-prompting-for-sudo-password-to-an-ubuntu-box)

[capistrano deployment with use_sudo=true - permissions problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923572/capistrano-deployment-with-use-sudo-true-permissions-problem)

So I added `default_run_options[:pty] = true` to deploy.rb, but I got just `undefined local variable or method default_run_options for main:Object`

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: default_run_options is probably only available in capistrano v2. Does the user you are deploying as have sudo access?

Comment: Thanks, now I deleted default_run_options. I wrote in visudo `username ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`.