# Capistrano sudo password prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I have a problem with capistrano and sudo prompt password. When I run `cap deploy` it asks me for sudo password but I type it and hit enter but it seems that it is still waiting for more input. How can I tell that I'm finished typing?

Answer (score 4):

Deployment process asks password not from you, but from executing process at your remote server so you can't access remote prompt. I have this problem once. Some solutions:

- (Bad). Use sudo_password in your deploy.rb
- (Good). Setup right and permissions to not to use sudo access at all.

Second advice much better :)

Comment: Additionally you can look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6057262/323249

Comment: so there is no way to pass password to this prompt? it would be very strang since this is recommended capistrano way?

Comment: If you deployment user is not root - then there's really not a way to do so. Use root as deployment user (if it's possible) or setup permissions for your current deployment user.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this in deploy.rb?

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```